# GROUP BY without a first NULL cell

Tags: mysql

These are the first 10 lines of my table :

[image: foo]

And this is the result i want to come up with :

[image: bar]

How can i make this result ?

And is it possible to write the correct query without displaying a null row in the name field when doing a group by ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The grouping looks like it should be on session_id_current_user with all fields other than avg max(ed) with an existence check to see if there is a name eg

```
SELECT t.session_id_current_user,
       max(t.name), max(email)...
       , AVG(t.spent_time) 
FROM table t 
where exists (select 1 from t t1 where t1.session_id_current_user = t.session_id_current_user and t1.name is not null)
group by t.session_id_current_user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as simple as this?

```
SELECT t.name, other_columns, AVG(t.spent_time) FROM table t where t.name is not null and length(trim(t.name))>0
group by t.name;
```

Comment: I did it, but the issue is that it doesn't return the correct value of the average time spent since it's only calculating the lines where name is not null. Though there are some sessions of the same user but without the name of the user that needs to be added to the calcul.

Comment: In this example, the user ALICE will have an average timeSpent of 2 seconds, but in the correct form, it's actually 1 second. (we calculate the sessions that he has while keeping the name of the user)